# What are "Instead of" Triggers?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

In SQL Server, what are `Instead Of` triggers?

Comment: what?  What are what insteead of triggers?

Comment: You are aware that SQL server ships with an extensive help system, you can access by pressing F1, don't you?  Try it out and you'll save some time.

Comment: Wow, that was some bad punctuation and sentence formation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Database Journal](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1437741/Simplifying-Instead-Of-Triggers.htm):

> What are "Instead Of" triggers?
>
> In previous versions of SQL Server,
>   **Triggers** were sections of code that
>   were attached to tables and executed
>   automatically after pre-defined
>   updates took place on a specified
>   table. These of course still exist in
>   SQL Server 2000 and above. **Instead Of Triggers**
>   are attached to a table in a similar
>   way, but the code inside them is
>   executed *in place of* the original
>   updating statement.

Comment: And nobody realized it was a bad idea to name them this way?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggers are actually very cool. In the past I've used instead of triggers on a 'read-only' view to make it behave like a table.

This is actually very cool.

You can even write these triggers in .NET if T-SQL isn't one of your strengths.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are basically used to enforce Business constraints. The Business constraints can be implemented in the following order: Entity Integrity(Primary/Unique Key), Domain Integrity(Check constraint),Referential Integrity(Foreign Key) and finally triggers.Triggers are used to enforce business constraints, which are complex.

Triggers are like stored procedures, which are automatically get executed based on Data Manipulation action. "Instead of Triggers" are used to handle data manipulations, which we  want to handle ourselves. Instead of `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` are written on a table to study the data and take the necessary action ourselves.

Eg. If you don't want `DELETE` to happen on table and want to monitor users, who are trying to delete data in table. We can write INSTEAD OF `TRIGGER` and write the `currentuser` information to Audit table.

Eg. If you want to throw custom messages for an user action. In an Exam timetable, if a user tries to have exam on weekend,we can throw a custom message that "It is Weekend.Take Rest"

Eg. If we have a view is defined on multiple tables and an insert is tried on it, we can have instead of trigger to carryout the corresponding insert in the base tables.